# ORA-00923 ORACLE ERROR

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

```
INSERT INTO FCR.TRANSACTION (TRX_UNIT, TRX_DATE, TRX_USR, 
         TRX_USR_SN, TRANSACTION_CODE,
         PRODUCT_CODE, CURRENCY_SHORT_DESCRIPTION, 
         AMOUNT_FC, EXCHANGE_RATE, AMOUNT_DC)
 SELECT SOURCE_SYSTEM_CHANNEL_CODE, to_char(TRANSACTION_DATE), 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 
    USER_CODE, USER_TRANSACTION_SERIAL_NUMBER, TRANSACTION_CODE, 
    PROFITS_PRODUCT_CODE, SHORT_DESCRIPTION, SOURCE_AMOUNT_FC, 
    SOURCE_EXCHANGE_RATE, SOURCE_AMOUNT_EUR
 FROM FCR.ORION_FCR_TRANSACTION
 WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = 'to_char(" + date + ", 'dd/mm/yyyy')'
```

The above query is giving me `ORA-00923 ERROR. FROM KEYWORD NOT FOUND IN POSITION.`

Can anyone please help me to solve the above problem.

I think that the error has something to do with the line in my C# code:

```
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = 'to_char(" + date + ", 'dd/mm/yyyy')'
```

Comment: You don't really need to write everything in uppercase. SQL has such a tradition; natural languages don't.

Comment: Why is to_char quoted as a string in the where clause?

Comment: SO syntax highlighting is great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the closing parentheses after TRANSACTION_DATE.

And the fact that you put the to_char in the WHERE within a string doesn't help either. :)

I'm not sure, but it might help if you use just a little indentations. It will be easier to spot typo's like this if your query is outlined in a more readable fashion.

```
INSERT INTO FCR.TRANSACTION (
  TRX_UNIT, 
  TRX_DATE, 
  TRX_USR, 
  TRX_USR_SN, 
  TRANSACTION_CODE, 
  PRODUCT_CODE, 
  CURRENCY_SHORT_DESCRIPTION, 
  AMOUNT_FC, 
  EXCHANGE_RATE, 
  AMOUNT_DC)
SELECT 
  SOURCE_SYSTEM_CHANNEL_CODE, 
  to_char(TRANSACTION_DATE), 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 
  USER_CODE, 
  USER_TRANSACTION_SERIAL_NUMBER, 
  TRANSACTION_CODE, 
  PROFITS_PRODUCT_CODE, 
  SHORT_DESCRIPTION, 
  SOURCE_AMOUNT_FC, 
  SOURCE_EXCHANGE_RATE, 
  SOURCE_AMOUNT_EUR
FROM 
  FCR.ORION_FCR_TRANSACTION
WHERE 
  TRANSACTION_DATE = 'to_char(" + date + ", 'dd/mm/yyyy')'
```

Comment: thanks but i removed the parentheses :INSERT INTO FCR.TRANSACTION (TRX_UNIT, TRX_DATE, TRX_USR, TRX_USR_SN, TRANSACTION_CODE, PRODUCT_CODE, CURRENCY_SHORT_DESCRIPTION, AMOUNT_FC, EXCHANGE_RATE, AMOUNT_DC)
SELECT SOURCE_SYSTEM_CHANNEL_CODE, to_char(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), USER_CODE, USER_TRANSACTION_SERIAL_NUMBER, TRANSACTION_CODE, PROFITS_PRODUCT_CODE, SHORT_DESCRIPTION, SOURCE_AMOUNT_FC, SOURCE_EXCHANGE_RATE, SOURCE_AMOUNT_EUR
FROM FCR.ORION_FCR_TRANSACTION
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = 'to_char(" + date + ", 'dd/mm/yyyy')'   and the error ora-00933:sql command not properly handled

Comment: ..and?  Did something happen?

Comment: @golezTrol--i tried your query but FROM keyword not found were expected error arose. Do you have any idea what I have wrong please>? thanks alot

Comment: That's because I just corrected the outlining in that query. I pointed you to the error: Remove the first closing parentheses in ` to_char(TRANSACTION_DATE), 'dd/mm/yyyy'), `.

Comment: After that you get a `SQL command not properly ended`, which is because of the syntax error in the WHERE expression.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this:

```
to_char(TRANSACTION_DATE), 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
```

should be this:

```
to_char(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
```

and this:

```
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = 'to_char(" + date + ", 'dd/mm/yyyy')'
```

should be this:

```
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = to_char(date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')'
```

Comment: I changed them but still is telling me sql command not properly ended. I am attaching my sql query :INSERT INTO FCR.TRANSACTION (TRX_UNIT, TRX_DATE, TRX_USR, TRX_USR_SN, TRANSACTION_CODE, PRODUCT_CODE, CURRENCY_SHORT_DESCRIPTION, AMOUNT_FC, EXCHANGE_RATE, AMOUNT_DC)
SELECT SOURCE_SYSTEM_CHANNEL_CODE, to_char(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), USER_CODE, USER_TRANSACTION_SERIAL_NUMBER, TRANSACTION_CODE, PROFITS_PRODUCT_CODE, SHORT_DESCRIPTION, SOURCE_AMOUNT_FC, SOURCE_EXCHANGE_RATE, SOURCE_AMOUNT_EUR
FROM FCR.ORION_FCR_TRANSACTION
WHERE TRANSACTION_DATE = 'to_char(date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')'

Comment: why do you have quotes around 'to_char(date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')' they're not needed

Answer (score 2):

After formatting to make it clearer it appears that you have added a ) in he select part

You have `SELECT SOURCE_SYSTEM_CHANNEL_CODE, to_char(TRANSACTION_DATE), 'dd/mm/yyyy'),`

I think you have added an extra end bracket for the to_char after TRANSACTION_DATE it might be

```
SELECT SOURCE_SYSTEM_CHANNEL_CODE, to_char(TRANSACTION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy'),
```

It helps to format code clearly and to use an editor that matches brackets.